# How to use FORM with tables and/or $_POST wont post

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I am trying to do a simple FORM - However right now, I press SUBMIT & nothing happens - the form activates, but no $_POST variables are received.

```
      echo "<hr>1aa<br />\n";
      echo "<PRE>\n";
      echo print_r($_POST);
      echo "</PRE>\n";
      var_dump($_POST);
      echo "<hr>2a<br />\n";
```

NOTHING is being received.

I have done hundreds of forms in the past - Even with OLD HTMNL - using tables,tr  & TD - the form sends no data...

i changed it to DIVS as below - still nothing..

Has anyone got any ideas ?

```
    <div style='text-align: center;'>
    <form  name="enter" action="/goods" method="post">
    <div style='float:left; '>
    <select name="goodsname">
    <option value='adrian'>Adrian</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style='float:left; '>
    <select name="goodsproducts">
    <option value='Dye'>Dye</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style='float:left; '>
    <input type='text' name='number' />
    </div>
    <div style='float:left; '>
    <input type="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: "goods" is not linked up I guess. Is the first block of code in "goods" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying specifying the extension of the link you are providing.
For example:  Action="/goods.php"

Comment: AH thanks  - i had /goods/index.php   when i had action='/goods'  it autoamtically redirected to /goods/index.php  but it didnt carry the $_POST variables. ive changed it to action='/goods/' with the trailing slash. it now works. thanks.....